# Algorithm to get mixed results based on sums

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have a table with products, one with characteristics and one with connections between products and characteristic.

Structure of table "products":

```
+----+------+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| id | name | max_quantity | morning | evening | afternoon |
+----+------+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

and "characteristics":

```
+----+----------------+
| id | characteristic |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | size           |
|  2 | weight         |
|  3 | length         |
+----+----------------+
```

and connection between products and characteristics "connections":

```
+----+------------+-------------------+
| id | product_id | characteristic_id |
+----+------------+-------------------+
```

I need to get a combined list of products which will have sum of size < 100, sum of weight < 50 and sum of length > 30 (100, 50, 30 are variables, I'm just posting as examples). Each product can be in a number of maximum "max_quantity" (from the products table), so not unique products.

I have two approaches: 1. a mysql query that will return everything as I described; 2. get a big set of results and process them later in PHP (using array manipulation). I couldn't find a suitable solution. If you could help me find a solution would be great.

As a bonus, I would like to get a proportion of 30% products with the field "morning" = 1, 30% products with field "evening" = 1, 40% products with field "afternoon" = 1.

Comment: depending on your data there can be several possible selections of products that fulfill your requirements. Do you just need any one of those, or do you have further restrictions? As for the bonus - you will need to specify as well what should happen if multiple/none solutions exist.

Comment: I need any one of those. If multiple solutions exists it should pick few of them randomly. There is no such a case like no solution.

Comment: While you can say that there shouldn't be such a case you can't be certain that there always will be a solution. Imagine a product table where each product has weight `>50` (for whatever reason). Then your above restrictions won't return a result.

Comment: Btw what should happen to the 30/30/40 percent values in case you can not split your product list exactly to these values (imagine some lists of 4 products fulfills your requirements - how do you split those to morning/evening/afternoon?)

Answer (score 0):

To get a result that matches your requirements you can do the following:

calculate the `size per lenght` and `weight per length` ratio for each product (set it to infinity if `lenght` is zero). Then distribute the products with the lowest weighted maximum first. If you do not get to a list of products that reaches the length-limit without exeeding your weight or size limits, there is no suitable solution!

This means you should order your products ascending by:

```
MAX(currentSize/currentWeight*(size/length),(weight/length))
```

where `currentSize` is the total size of all products in currently in your list and `currentWeight` is the total weight of all products in currently in your list. Recalculate this every time after you added a product to your result list and then add the first product of that list until you reach your length-limit.

If you want to satisfy your bonus restriction, you can split up the product table into three individual tables and pick a product of each of these in turn (starting with the afternoon- table and picking a 10th one from the afternoon-table everytime you added 3 products from each table to get close to a 30/30/40 distribution).

Comment: Thank you. I understand the ratio part, but is there any reason for choosing to divide per length and not per size or per weight? Could you write an example (a query even though with mistakes)? What about having more than 3 characteristics? I am not sure I got the last example (what is currentSize, currentWeight?).

Comment: The reason why i was dividing by length is that length is the only of your characteristics which needs to be *greater* than some limit. Thus I suggested adding products to your list which have the lowest size/length or weigth/length ratio depending on the total size/weigth of the products already added to your productlist. Solving this problem for arbitrary number of characteristics is not trivial. Look into the simplex algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) for a way to find solutions for linear optimization problems.

Comment: calculating the currentSize and currentWeight everytime after you added a new product is necessary to pick the next product appropriately. Imagine you have 3 products (all with length 20). ProductA has weight 40 and size 20, Product B has weigth 5 and size 70 and product C has weight 30 and size 60. Try to figure out what my suggested algorithm would do without using the currentSize/currentWeight.